# how to update Tree table which is a session scoped and resolving the issue of command button for intermediate nodes

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am working on prime faces tree table. I have a list of students and for each students I am trying to display all possible teachers they can undergo training.

I have kept managed bean class named TreeviewBean which is a session scoped and I have a constructor where I am initializing the root value as shown below. I have initialized inside a constructor and not in get root method. Initially constructor gets called for first time and tree table works absolutely fine. Problem comes when new students are created in different page. since the tree view bean is session scoped, constructor is not calling every time and list of students is not updating as a result tree view is not displaying the right value. I have changed to request scope, here performance hinders and command button on editing teachers fails. How could I solve the problem?

```
     @ManagedBean(name="treeViewBean")
     @SessionScoped
     public class TreeViewBean implements Serializable {  

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            private Object selectedNode;

            private TreeNode root;  

            private TreeData treedata;

            public TreeViewBean() {  
               systemstud= new ManageStudentsDelegate();
               list  sys = systemstud.getAllnfo();
               root = new DefaultTreeNode("root", null);
               for(StudBean s : sys){
                treedata= new TreeData(s,"students");
                    TreeNode system = new DefaultTreeNode(treedata, root); 
                    if(s.getteachers()!=null){
                  for(teachBean serv : s.getteachers()){
                     treedata= new TreeData(serv,"teachers");
                     TreeNode service = new DefaultTreeNode(treedata, system);
                   }
                    }
               }
            }     

            public TreeNode getRoot() { 
                return root;  
            }  

            public void setRoot(TreeNode root) {  
                this.root = root;  
            }  

            public String editStudentOrteacher(){
                             system.out.println("edit");
            }

            public Object getSelectedNode() {
                return selectedNode;
            }

            public void setSelectedNode(Object selectedNode) {
                this.selectedNode = selectedNode;
            }
   }
```

XHTML Code:

```
 <p:treeTable value="#{treeViewBean.root}" var="system"  id="treeTable">  

        <p:column style="width:150px" >  
            <f:facet name="header">  
                Name  
            </f:facet>  
            <h:outputText value="#{system.stud.name}" /> 
            <h:outputText value="#{system.teach.name}"/> 
        </p:column>  
        <p:column >
            <p:commandButton action="#{treeViewBean.editStudentOrteacher}" process="@this">
            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{treeViewBean.selectedNode}" value="#{system}"></f:setPropertyActionListener>
            </p:commandButton>
       </p:column>

 </p:treeTable>
```

Comment: if your problem can be solved by invoking the code in constructor whenever you add new student then you can inject reference of this SessionScoped bean to the view scoped bean and call a routine to inform this bean of changes.

Comment: Sorry I thought the other bean which you are using is ViewScoped. Please have look at the answer and try it.

Comment: @cpz: I have tried  this. Problem is inside a constructor injected property becomes null and out side the constructor I am able to get values of injected bean ie student list since value of injected property is null in constructor, I am not able to view the page

Comment: There is definitely something wrong at your part, could you please fix your code for these two lines `systemstud= new ManageStudentsDelegate();
               list  sys = systemstud.getAllnfo();` there is unknown variable "systemstud" and what is "list" in these lines and also post more information about other bean and where this injected property is being null as you specify.

Answer (score 0):

In your other bean which manages handling of new student addition, inject reference to this SessionScoped TreeViewBean.

In the other bean you can do it like this

```
 @ManagedBean(name="otherBean")
 @ViewScoped
 public class OtherBean implements Serializable {

      @ManagedProperty(value="#{treeViewBean}")
      private TreeViewBean tvBean;

      public void setTreeViewBean(TreeViewBean tvBean) {
           this.tvBean = tvBean;
      }

      private void updateTVBean(){
              //here you can call some method on #{treeViewBean} to update that
              tvBean.someMethod(); //indicative only
      }
 }
```